# How to move an object in a loop with arrow keys

Tags: java, loops, object

I'm trying to move a square in a continuous loop that leaves a trail behind itself while the loop is running (think of the BMtron game), but when I use my keylistener to move the square, the screen freezes, and the object does not move although the loop continues to run. Here is a snippet:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("keyPressed");
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        //moveRight();
        //down.start();
        U = false;
        D = false;
        L = false;
        R = true;
        while (R = true) {
            x = x + 2;
            repaint();
            System.out.println("Right");
        }
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        R = false;
        U = false;
        D = false;
        L = true;
        while (L = true) {
            //moveLeft();
            x = x - 2;
            repaint();
            System.out.println("Left");
        }
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        R = false;
        U = false;
        L = false;
        D = true;
        while (D = true) {
            //moveDown();
            y = y + 2;
            repaint();
            System.out.println("Down");
        }
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        R = false;
        D = false;
        L = false;
        U = true;
        //System.out.println("");
        while (U = true) {
            y = y - 2;
            repaint();
            System.out.println("Up");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the entire code, let me know.

Comment: the while loop should not be in the key event handler

Comment: `while(R=true)` this loop (and the others) is nonsense. First of all, it should be `while(R==true)` (or just `while(R)`) and secondly, you're not changing the value of `R` inside the loop. So how should the loop be exited? `R` will never become `false`.

Comment: The way I had it in my head was. Using the key listener when you pressed an arrow key. The listener would apply the corresponding action. Ex. If you pressed the right arrow key the listener would move the object to right infinitely until you pressed another key. So if the object is moving to the right, it would keep doing so until you pressed..the down arrow key for instance, then it would shut off the R Boolean and activate the D boolean. At least that's what I had in my head. I'm very new to Java (and programming)

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the expression of the assignment returns the **assigned** value. Note your loop:

```
while(R = true)
        ↑
```

You need to compare and not to assign.

Your loop will be always executed as it's like writing `while(true)` (`true` is the assigned value), and you'll be running an infinite loop which freezes your program. That's why it's very recommended to not use `==` and `!=` when we compare booleans, it can prevent possible bugs. Instead, just write:

```
while(R)  //same as while(R == true) but please don't use ==
```

Comment: I wonder what will happen if he changes that. If the program "stuck" in one of the loops and the user presses another key in a different direction, will the listener catch that? Or will the program miss this event, because it still "stuck" in the loop? I guess it would be nice to know if the `ActionListener` fires its methods in a separate thread :D.

Comment: @Tom It depends on how the listener is implemented. If it's just an anonymous implementation, it'll be executed within the same thread that actually calls it. If you're using a [worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for example, it will be ran in a different thread.

Comment: well, with that in mind do you have suggestions on how to resolve this problem? I'm very new to java so I'm not sure how to make the object move continuously while not freezing my program.

Comment: @AndrewMacMillan think what event should break the loop. For example removing your finger from the up arrow..

Comment: Pressing a different key would break the loop. So if the object is going right, it will continue to do so until you crash, or change directions by pressing a different arrow key